# Pigeonhole principle help with integer sequence

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Can someone help me understand the following logic using the pigeonhole principle:

If a sequence of $n$ integers $x_1, x_2,...,x_n\;(n\geq2,x_i \geq 0)$ sums to $n^2-3n+2$, then either of the following is true:

- at least one $x_i$ satisfies $x_i \geq n-1$
- at least two $x_i$ satisfy $x_i =n-2$

Comment: Don't bother with pigeonhole principle.  Suppose otherwise.  Then at most one $x_i=n-2$ and all other satisfy $x_i\leq n-3$.  Then the largest possible sum of these is?

Comment: As for the "*exactly one of the following is true*" that is incorrect.  It could be the case that both are true simultaneously.  With $n=7$ you have $20+5+5+0+0+0+0=30 = 7^2-3\cdot 7 + 2$ for instance.  It should have read *at least* one of the following is true.